# How to associate files to post with Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, html, laravel, file-upload

I am using Laravel for my web app and I want to associate files to my posts in indepent way with his own form, but I have some problems

My routes (I am using a auth control package, but actually I am admin):

```
Route::post('file', 'fileController@store')->name('file.store')
    ->middleware('permission:file.create');
Route::get('file', 'fileController@index')->name('file.index')
    ->middleware('permission:file.index');
Route::get('file/create/', 'fileController@create')->name('file.create')
    ->middleware('permission:file.create');
Route::put('file/{id}', 'fileController@update')->name('file.update')
    ->middleware('permission:file.edit');
Route::get('file/{id}', 'fileController@show')->name('file.show')
    ->middleware('permission:file.show');
Route::delete('file/{id}', 'fileController@destroy')->name('file.destroy')
    ->middleware('permission:file.destroy');
Route::get('file/{id}/edit', 'fileController@edit')->name('file.edit')
    ->middleware('permission:file.edit');
Route::get('download/{filename}', 'fileController@download')->name('file.download')
    ->middleware('permission:file.download');
```

My migration:

```
    Schema::create('files', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('files_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('filenames');
        $table->integer('fileable_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('fileable_type');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

My File Model:

```
class File extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'filenames', 'project_id'
];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

My Project Model:

```
public function files()
{
    return $this->morphMany(File::class, 'fileable')->whereNull('files_id');
}
```

My Controller to store:

```
class FileController extends Controller
{
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
            'filenames' => 'required',
            'project_id' => 'required',
            // 'filenames.*' => 'mimes:doc,pdf,docx,zip'
    ]);

    if($request->hasfile('filenames'))
    {
        foreach($request->file('filenames') as $file)
        {
            $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move(public_path().'/files/', $name);  
            $data[] = $name;  
        }
    }

    $file= new File();
    $file->filenames = $request->get('filenames');
    $file->filenames= $name;
    $file->user()->associate($request->user());
    $project = Project::findOrFail($request->get('project_id'));
    $project->files()->save($file);
    $file->save();

    return back();
}

public function download( $filename = '' ) { 
// Check if file exists in storage directory
$file_path = public_path() . '/files/' . $filename;  

if ( file_exists( $file_path ) ) { 
    // Send Download 
    return \Response::download( $file_path, $filename ); 
    } else { 
    return back()->with('info', 'Archivo no existe en el servidor');
    }
}
```

The Form in blade:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('file.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="input-group hdtuto control-group lst increment" >
  <input type="file" name="filenames[]" class="myfrm form-control">
  <input type="hidden" name="project_id" value="{{ $project->id }}" />
  <div class="input-group-btn"> 
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"><i class="fldemo glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Add</button>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top:10px">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Foreach to download files:

```
@foreach($project->files as $file)
  <li>{{ $file->user->name }}: <a href="{{ url('/download/')}}/{{$file->filenames}}" download> {{$file->filenames}}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

I send files from Project Controll

Comment: `$project = Project::find($request->get('project_id'));` If this is returning `null`, you can't call `$project->files() ...`. Check what `$request->get('project_id')` contains and ensure you have a `Project` for that ID.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the first error message is because the `Project` with the `id` you get from `Request` is not found in the `Database` and returns `null` instead of an `object`. That would mean you are indeed calling `files()` method on `null`. To resolve this there are multiple steps.

1.) Make sure `project_id` is inside the `Request` at all times:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'filenames' => 'required',
    'project_id' => 'required',
    // 'filenames.*' => 'mimes:doc,pdf,docx,zip'
]);
```

2.) Make sure to check for `project` if it exists after retrieving it from database, this can be done in two ways.

a) You can either `find` the `project` or `throw an Exception` if it's not found:

```
$project = Project::findOrFail($request->get('project_id');`
```

b) You can check with a simple if statement if it does not exist and do something

```
$project = Project::find($request->get('project_id');
if (!$project) {
    // Project not found in database
    // Handle it
}
```

Comment: I added the code findOrFail, the form saves the file in public_path (). '/ Files /', but does not create a record in the database

Comment: Did you `use` the right class `File` at the top of your `Controller`?

Comment: Also, you need to `$file->save();` in order to create both `File object inside the database` and to be able to `link $file with $project` because, `files()->save($file)` relies on `$file->id` which is being created upon `$file->save()` not before

Comment: That's! Work well, finally. Thank you. I will change the post with the correct data for the others.